# FilePicker class cannot be found in Xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, upload

I'm creating a Xamarin forms app which enables user uploads. I have installed the latest version of the Xamarin.Essentials package but the classes and methods which I would expect to be available cannot be found. I can move ahead with the xamarin.plugins.filepicker package but this is not well documented and I would prefer to use the standard library. Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated! The default is below.

'''

```
    async Task<FileResult> PickAndShow(PickOptions options)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync();
            if (result != null)
            {
                Text = $"File Name: {result.FileName}";
                if (result.FileName.EndsWith("jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                    result.FileName.EndsWith("png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();
                    Image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // The user canceled or something went wrong
        }
    }
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

For the `Xamarin.Essentials package`, update to the latest version on both Xamarin.Form NuGet Package and Android NuGet Package. After that you could fix the errors like below.

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'PickOptions' could not be found (are you 
missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

For the usage of `Xamarin.Essentials: File Picker`, you could check the MS document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?tabs=android

If you wanna the source file, you could download from the link below. https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/tree/main/Xamarin.Essentials/FilePicker